# How to copy directories where the directory name contains a string

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, cp

I'd like to pull out any directories where the directory name contains certain strings (people's names!). Specifically in this case `Rob\ G` or `Marwa \E`.

I've read around and can see how to do this for filenames that are within a list specified in a spreadsheet using this:

```
mkdir -p destination_folder || exit 1
while IFS= read -r name; do
    find . -path ./destination_folder -prune -o \
        -type f -name "$name" -exec cp {} destination_folder \;
done <filenames.txt
```

But I can't work out how to make it work for copying whole directories. Here's a truncated version of the file directory tree I'm looking in.
Any help much appreciated!

```
$ tree -L 3
.
|-- 2020
|   |-- 10\ October
|   |   |-- Aiyin
|   |   |-- Rob\ G
|   |   |-- Yada
|   |   |-- Yavuz
|   |   |-- Ying\ H
|   |   `-- sophie
|   `-- 9\ September
|       `-- Nacho
`-- 2021
    |-- 1\ January
    |   |-- Agnes
    |   |-- Marwa\ E
    |   |-- Ilaria\ M
    |   |-- Sameer\ Bahal
    |   |-- Sandra\ C
    |   |-- Xin
    |   `-- Yada
    |-- 10\ October
    |   |-- Aiyin
    |   |-- Alba
    |   |-- Marwa\ E
    |   |-- Xin
    |   |-- Ying
    |   `-- Rob\ G
    |-- 7\ July
    |   |-- Aakash\ M
    |   |-- Aiyin
    |   |-- Rob\ G
    |`--|-- Alexia
```

Comment: You mean "the directory name contains a **space**"? They are all strings, after all.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of redirecting the file that contains the names to the command, parse the names.txt-file using echo and sed *(to escape the backslashes)*, like so:

```
mkdir -p destination_folder || exit 1

echo "$(sed 's/\\/\\\\/g' names.txt)" | while IFS= read -r name; do
    find . -type d -name "$name" -exec cp -r {} destination_folder \;
done
```

Other additions are the `-r` flag to `cp`, so that it copies directories and their contents recursively.

Also, `find` a directory with `-type d` flag.

Your `names.txt` must contain the exact name of the folder you are after, each folder on their own line.
As per your example, if you want to copy the contents of `Rob\ G` and `Marwa\ E`, your `names.txt` should be:

```
Rob\ G
Marwa\ E
```

Now bear in mind that this will copy all the files in such folders over to `destination_folder/NAME`. If you have two identically named folders, which contain identically named files, the **previous file will be overwritten!** *(For example if `./2020/10\ October/Rob\ G` and `./2021/7\ July/Rob\ G` both contain a file called `exam.txt`, only one `exam.txt` will remain in the destination)*

If this is a concern, you could try adding some ordering or renaming functionality with the `-exec` action.

Comment: There is no need to get the content of the file and then echo it to the pipe. What I usually do is `sed 's/change this/to this/g' filename.txt | while read line; do`. By doing so, the $line will contain the whole line regardless of spaces in the middle of the lines.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

I have used `locate` to find the files and folders with the specific name.  Please note if you do not have **locate** on your system use the following command `sudo apt install mlocate`

```
locate Rob > name.txt
```

Here Rob is the folder name we are searching for and we have saved all the possibilities in a text file with the 'name.txt'.

```
grep -wi "Rob" name.txt
```

Using grep command we are searching for Rob in name.txt. Here `-w` is to find exact word and `i` is to find for upper and lower case possiblities.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the `grep` for filtering your pattern. This script will copy the directories that contain

`anyword with \ space anyletter/`

and copy all that directories to `destination`

```
#!/bin/bash
paths=($(ls -d $PWD/*/*/*/ | grep -- '[a-zA-Z]*\\ [A-Z]/'))
j=0
len=${#paths[@]}
while [[ $j -lt $len ]]
do
    echo $j ${paths[$j]} ${paths[$j+1]}
    cp -r "${paths[$j]} ${paths[$j+1]}" /path/to/destination/
    j=$(($j+2))
done
```

You can also use your pattern by simply modifying the grep command

```
paths=($(ls -d $PWD/*/*/*/ | grep -- 'Rob\\ G/'))
```

Note: In copying or moving it will override the directory with the same name. To avoid overriding you can use symbolic links or place `$j` at the end of the copy command.

```
ln -s "${paths[$j]} ${paths[$j+1]}" /home/sahil/Documents/destination/$j
```

or

```
cp -r "${paths[$j]} ${paths[$j+1]}" /home/sahil/Documents/destination/$j
```

**Explanation:**

1. Filter the pattern using `grep` and make an array from `grep` output.
2. Array's name is `paths`.
3. Found a length of an array using `len=${#paths[@]}`.
4. Placed a while loop.
5. In `${paths[$j]}=/path/to/Rob\` and In `${paths[$j+1]}=G/`. So I concatenate both by writing this way `${paths[$j]} ${paths[$j+1]}` for making an absolute path to the match pattern. That is why I am incrementing `$j` two times.
6. Then I use the same concatenation for copying into a destination.
7. I used the symbolic link and `$j` at the end of the copy command to avoid overriding.